# Only String Keys supported in Dataset's Association Query?

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Given data:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]
```

This Association Query works:

```
titanic[All, <| "newKey" -> "age"|>]
```

But numeric or Symbol Keys,

```
titanic[All, <| 1 -> "age"|>]
titanic[All, <| newKey -> "age"|>]
```

fail with error: `Missing[KeyAbsent]`. Known issue?

Numeric keys are especially conveninent for multiple, parametrized queries. Currently, that requires the workaround `KeyMap[ToString]` and later back `ToExpression`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, the `<| field -> op |>` constructor notation specifically requires string keys. I'll relax that -- should show up in 10.0.2.

Comment: For what it's worth: I noticed that if one relaxes that condition on ``Dataset`Query`PackagePrivate`comp`` then the correct results are generated.  But then the result does not render properly in the front-end unless a similar relaxation is made to ``Dataset`FormattingDispatch`PackagePrivate`tocolboxes``.  I suspect that there could be similar knock-on consequences elsewhere.

Comment: @WReach it's not quite as bad as that: if we make the output type of ApplyThrough (the underlying operator form of <| |>) be an Assoc rather than Struct when keys aren't all strings, then everything downstream will Just Work. We lose a bit of type information -- but the only alternative, which is to allow Structs to contain keys of an arbitrary kind, is an invasive change that is unlikely to happen soon.